# Visual Studioで作成したアプリが別のPCで動作しない

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Visual StudioでOpenGLを使ったアプリケーションを作成し、インストーラーも作りました。

開発用コンピューター内でインストーラーを実行するとうまく動きました。
しかし、別のコンピューター内でインストーラーを実行すると

"openal32.dll"
"ucrtbased.dll"
"vcruntime140d.dll"

以上のファイルが存在しない旨のエラーが出ました。

どれもdllが存在しないってだけなので、開発用コンピューター内から該当するdllファイルを持ってくることでこのエラーは消えましたが、別のエラーが発生しました。

```
"アプリケーションを正しく起動できませんでした。(0xc000007b)"
```

開発用コンピュータで動作しているため、32bitバイナリデータに64bitのdllを入れてしまっているというミスも考えにくく詰まっています。

何か解決できそうな情報がある方は教えてください。

(ちなみに開発用コンピューターと別のコンピューター1台ずつの検証でしたので合計2台でしか検証できていません。しかし十分だとも思いますが。)

---

#### 追記1

別コンピューターのグラフィックドライバは最新でした。

また、
別PC = Windows 10 Pro (64bit) , Intel HD Graphics 4400
開発PC = Windows 10 Enterprise (64bit) , Intel HD Graphics 4000
です。

---

#### 追記2

Visual Studioのビルドモードを確認しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これでCTRL+Bでリリース版がビルドできると思っていたのですが、違うのでしょうか？
ビルド後のexeとその関連ファイルはReleaseディレクトリ下に生成されました。

---

#### 追記3

ランタイムパッケージのインストールを別PCに行っていなかったためインストールをしました。
しかし相変わらず

"ucrtbased.dll"
"vcruntime140d.dll"

が要求され、

```
"アプリケーションを正しく起動できませんでした。(0xc000007b)"
```

も同様でした。dllも32bit用を使用しているみたいなのですが。

もうしばらく頑張ってダメそうであればvsデータをすべて抹消してvsデータの作り直しをします。
なぜデバッグモードになってしまっているのか...
できれば今後の方のためにも解決したいところです

---

#### 追記4

「構成マネージャー」と「プロパティ -> C/C++ -> コード生成」の画像を追加しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

#### 追記5

念のため、元々"C++によるデスクトップ開発"ワークロードでしたが"ユニバーサルWindowsプラットフォーム"ワークロードで再構成してみることにします。

Comment: とりあえず何かつかめるまでグラフィックドライバの更新をしてみようと思います。

Comment: それぞれのPCについてWindowsのバージョンや32bit or 64bit等の情報なども記載されていると回答のヒントになるかもしれません。質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、必要に応じて追記してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。情報を追記しました。何か気になることやピンときたことがあれば情報提供をお願いします。

Comment: dllはどこから入手しましたか？私のPCでucrtbasedを検索したところ30件くらいヒットしました。ucrtbasedとvcruntime140dついては、ともかくvisual studioの再配布可能パッケージをインストールしてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: すいません確認したいのですが、このランタイムパッケージを https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads からDLしてインストールしました(開発用PCに。また厳密にいえば再インストール)。　つまり通常であればVS内でRELEASEビルドを行うだけで（VS内で特に設定なしで）ランタイムパッケージごとビルドされた実行可能ファイルが出力されるっという考えでよいのでしょうか。　そしてどのPC内でも実行可能ファイルによりパッケージを取得してこれるような仕組みであると...違いますか？

Comment: いえ、再配布可能パッケージは実行する環境にインストールする必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。とりあえずパッケージは入れました。

Comment: 1.アクティブソリューション構成をReleaseにした状態で構成マネージャのスクショをお願いします。Debug/Releaseを選択するプルダウンの中から開けます。  2.再配布～をインストールした後は配置するファイルに拾ってきたdllは含めないでください

Comment: 3. <プロジェクト>のプロパティ->構成プロパティ->C/C++->コード生成->ランタイムライブラリ　の項目の確認もお願いします。

Comment: スクショをとってみました。アプリケーション名はAAAAAっと合成で改名しました。AAAAA Installer はVisual studio installer projectから生成したプロジェクトになります。

Comment: 「"ユニバーサルWindowsプラットフォーム"ワークロード」はまた別の迷路に入りそうで止めた方が良いでしょう。それよりも、私が最後に紹介した`Dependencies`で、プログラムやインストーラーの各プロジェクトの生成物をチェックした方が状況をつかむのに早そうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。とりあえずuwpのセットアップ完了まで行きましたので先にやってみます。windowsのリファレンスっぽいサイトから見るにエディション違いだと完全に別OS扱いになる部分があるらしくとりあえずそれを検証してみようと思います。ダメであれば足掛かりを探すためにkunifさんのやりかたでやってみます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"ucrtbased.dll"
"vcruntime140d.dll"

最後に d が付いているのはデバッグモード用でしょう。
コンパイル時のDebug/Releaseモードが混在しているのではないですか？

x86は32bitモードを表しています。

インストールパッケージ内に単一の.exeだけが存在するなら考えにくいですが、
大概は.dllも使うか作るかするはずなので、どれかがデバッグモード用でコンパイル
あるいはリンクされているのでしょう。
(コンパイルのモードはReleaseでもリンクの指定はDebug用とかもあり得るかも？)

それから0xc000007bは検索すると32bit/64bitの混在というのが出てきますね。
[アプリケーションエラー 0xc000007bで起動できない](https://hayakute.kantan-sakusaku.com/windows/2018/0119165256/)
可能性は無くは無いです。

---

vcruntime140(おそらくucrtbaseも)については、使っているVisualStudioの版数2015/2017/2019と32bit/64bitに対応した再頒布可能パッケージをダウンロードしてインストールしてください。
[最新のサポートされる Visual C++ のダウンロード](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)
対応版数が違ってもみんな同じファイル名なので注意してください。
開発用PCの中からファイル名だけで拾ってくると、間違いやすいでしょうし、ランタイムのバグ修正等に対応できなくなります。

Windows 8.1以前用のucrtbaseはこちらかも。
[Windows での汎用の C ランタイムの更新プログラム](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows)

---

関連は無いですが、私が以前に回答を出した質問の中に、答えとは関係なくグラフィックスドライバを最新の物にしたら直ったというのがあったので、ドライバのアップデートも意味はあるかもしれません。

---

他に参考になるのはこの辺でしょうか。

[WindowsアプリケーションでOpenGLを使いたい](https://teratail.com/questions/104717)
[Visual Studio 2017でOpenGLを動かせるようにする](https://qiita.com/SonoT/items/4387ec1c8d7af8979b35)
[C言語でOpenGL：Visual Studio 2019のclコマンドでGLUTを使う](https://qiita.com/enonoco/items/d6241fc99d050f6a5c00)
[再頒布可能パッケージ 現在のバージョンのWindows C++用OpenGLをインストールするにはどうすればよいですか?](https://code-examples.net/ja/q/11201cd)
[その１ ライブラリのインストールとOpenGLの初期化](http://marupeke296.com/OGL_No1_Install.html)
[windowsでopenGL環境を構築するための手順](https://qiita.com/kdotsaito/items/e34b32392099e1f13466)

---

.exe/.dllの依存関係を調べるなら、DependencyWalker(今はDependencies?)で調べられるのでは？
[プログラムやDLLファイルの依存関係がわかる「Dependency Walker」](https://webcli.jp/topics/dependencywalker/)
[覚書 : Dependency Walkerはもう古い! Windows 10ならDependenciesを使え!](https://frontl1ne.net/2018/12/dependency-walker-is-too-old-use-dependencies/)

Comment: それデバッグってことだったんですね。原因とすればほかにないかもしれません。確認しましたが、こちらのvisualstudio上では"Release / x86"でした。この状態でctrl+BでビルドすればOKだと思っていたのですが、これではVSの操作が違いますか？

Comment: おはようございます。回答ありがとうございます。無事正常起動しました。Dependenciesで調べてみたところ一部のdllファイル内で"ucrtbased.dll"　"vcruntime140d.dll"　を要求していたことがわかりました。つまりはそのdllがdebugビルドされたdllだったということです。そのdllをRelease用にリビルドしたものを呼び出すことで正常起動しました。