# dllが開発環境のPCでは認識されるが他のPCでは認識されない

Tags: visual-c++

visual c++ 2017 でx86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017からdllを作成しました。

開発環境ではそのdllは正しく動いたのですが、そのdllを他のpcにコピーしたところ認識されませんでした。（dllが認識されていればアプリケーションで現れるはずの選択肢が現れない）
エラーなどは全くでていません。

ライブラリが足りないのかと思いg++の-staticに相当するリンクオプションを探してみたのですが、見つからず、どうしていいかわからなくなってしまいました。
どうすれば開発環境以外のPCでもdllを認識させられるでしょうか
よろしくお願いします。

makefileは以下のようになっています。

```
CORE_DIR = ../..
MY_DIR = e:/irensei19

CC =  cl
CFLAGS =  /c -I../.. -I$(MY_DIR) - 
I$(MY_DIR)/tiny-dnn-1.0.0a2 /F 67108864 /bigobj /O2 /arch:AVX /EHsc

OBJS = airandom.obj game.obj StringData.obj \
    irensei_rule_description.obj 
    irensei_ai_descripter.obj \
    Init.obj Point.obj PointSet.obj Board.obj 
    MyGame.obj MinSet.obj Territory.obj MCTAI.obj 
    MCTAI2.obj MCTAI3.obj MCTAI4.obj UCTNode.obj \
    Board8.obj PointSet8.obj Board13.obj 
    PointSet13.obj  DataBase.obj Pattern13.obj 
    Pattern19.obj Feature.obj DNNAI.obj DNNAI2.obj 
    DNNMove.obj TestAI.obj

    OBJS2 = Init.obj Point.obj PointSet.obj 
    Board.obj MyGame.obj MinSet.obj Territory.obj 
    MCTAI.obj UCTNode.obj \
    Board8.obj PointSet8.obj Board13.obj 
    PointSet13.obj MCTAI2.obj DataBase.obj

airandom.dll: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) /LD -O2  $(OBJS)
    cp airandom.dll e:\irensei

Init.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(MY_DIR)/Init.cpp

Point.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/Point.cpp

DataBase.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/DataBase.cpp

PointSet.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/PointSet.cpp

Board.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/Board.cpp

MyGame.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)   MyGame.cpp 

MinSet.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/MinSet.cpp

Territory.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/Territory.cpp

MCTAI.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/MCTAI.cpp

MCTAI2.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/MCTAI2.cpp

MCTAI3.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/MCTAI3.cpp

MCTAI4.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/MCTAI4.cpp

MCTAI_mt.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/MCTAI_mt.cpp

MCTAI_mt2.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/MCTAI_mt2.cpp

TestAI.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/TestAI.cpp

DLAI.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/DLAI.cpp

EvalAI.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/EvalAI.cpp

Feature.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/Feature.cpp


Board8.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/Board8.cpp

PointSet8.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/PointSet8.cpp

Board13.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/Board13.cpp

PointSet13.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/PointSet13.cpp

Pattern13.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/Pattern13.cpp

Pattern19.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/Pattern19.cpp

EvalDL.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/EvalDL.cpp

DNNAI.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/DNNAI.cpp

DNNAI2.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/DNNAI2.cpp

DNNMove.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/DNNMove.cpp


UCTNode.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(MY_DIR)/UCTNode.cpp

airandom.obj: airandom.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) airandom.cpp


aiirandom.obj: aiirandom.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  aiirandom.c

game.obj: $(CORE_DIR)/game.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CORE_DIR)/game.cpp

StringData.obj: $(CORE_DIR)/StringData.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CORE_DIR)/StringData.cpp

irensei_ai_descripter.obj: 
$(CORE_DIR)/irensei_ai_descripter.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) 
$(CORE_DIR)/irensei_ai_descripter.c

irensei_rule_description.obj: 
$(CORE_DIR)/irensei_rule_description.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) 
$(CORE_DIR)/irensei_rule_description.c

clean:
    rm *.obj *.dll
```

Comment: コピー先のフォルダは環境変数のPATHに含まれているもの、またはアプリケーションのカレントフォルダでしょうか？あとはシステムフォルダとか。[DLLの検索](http://eternalwindows.jp/windevelop/dll/dll05.html)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。コピー先はアプリケーションのカレントフォルダです。

Comment: その場合、作成したDLLから更にリンクしているDLLが無かったのかもしれません。イベントログに記録とかは無いですか？あるいは作成したDLLを[Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)で調べればわかるかもしれません。またはこちらの記事も参考に情報を集めてみてください。[Visual Studioで作成したアプリが別のPCで動作しない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/57271/26370)

Comment: すいません、解決しました。コンパイルオプションに/arch:AVXを付けていたのですが、他のパソコンというのがかなり古いパソコンでAVXを搭載してなかったのが原因みたいです。/arch:SSE2にしたら選択肢が現れました。今時AVXもないとは…ちなみにDependenciesはビルドしようとしたらエラーになったのでとりあえずDependency walkerで見てみたら依存関係はOKでした。ご回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

コメントで解決されたようですので、回答として編集・転記いたします。

> コンパイルオプションに`/arch:AVX`を付けていたのですが、他のパソコンというのがかなり古いパソコンでAVXを搭載してなかったのが原因みたいです。

> `/arch:SSE2`にしたら選択肢が現れました。今時AVXもないとは…
> ちなみにDependenciesはビルドしようとしたらエラーになったのでとりあえずDependency walkerで見てみたら依存関係はOKでした。

Answer (score 0):

> g++の-staticに相当するリンクオプション

`CFLAGS`に[`/MT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=vs-2019)を追加するのはどうでしょうか？